# JavaScript - return false from function is not working?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I m calling a javascript function on asp.net button client click and want to prevent post back. function works but it do not stop to be posted back. My Javascript is:

```
function User2Check()
    {
        var user2id=document .getElementById("txtP2UserName");
        var user2password=document .getElementById("txtP2Password");

        if(user2id.value=='' & user2password.value!='')
        {
            alert("User name is required");
            user2id=document .getElementById("txtP2UserName").foucs();
            e.preventDefault();                
            return false;
        }
        if(user2id.value!='' & user2password.value=='')
        {
            alert("Password is required");
            user2id=document .getElementById("txtP2UserPassword").foucs();
            e.preventDefault();                
            return false;

        }


    }
```

The I am calling this function is:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" OnClientClick="return User2Check();" TabIndex="12" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

plz guide.

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript takes a parameter but the call from the button's OnClientClick has no parameter. I would think since e is null, the function terminates or returns before returning false but since `focus()` calls are before calling anything on e, the function seems to be working.

Comment: I tried by removing argument but no luck. I also tried to pass argument but again it did not work.

Comment: while removing the argument from the function, did you also remove it form the function body? And, ya as indicated by steve, you have a typo, it should be `focus()` not `foucs()`

Answer (score 1):

you should use `&&` instead of `&`

```
if(user2id.value!='' && user2password.value=='')
```

AND : Function needs an argument, but you are calling with no argument

You can do it as

```
function User2Check(e)
{
    var user2id=document .getElementById("txtP2UserName");
    var user2password=document .getElementById("txtP2Password");

    if(user2id.value=='')
    {
        alert("User name is required");
        user2id=document .getElementById("txtP2UserName").focus();
        e.preventDefault();                
        return false;
    }
    if(user2password.value=='')
    {
        alert("Password is required");
        user2id=document .getElementById("txtP2UserPassword").focus();
        e.preventDefault();                
        return false;
    }

return true;
```

}

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" OnClientClick="return User2Check(event);" TabIndex="12" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Comment: here you use "Function needs an argument, but you are calling with no argument" but it's not necessary.its work well.

Answer (score 1):

You use below code and remove " e.preventDefault();" from code.

```
function User2Check()
{
var user2id=document .getElementById("txtP2UserName");
var user2password=document .getElementById("txtP2Password");

if(user2id.value=='')
{
    alert("User name is required");
    user2id=document .getElementById("txtP2UserName").focus();
    return false;
}
if(user2password.value=='')
{
    alert("Password is required");
    user2id=document .getElementById("txtP2UserPassword").focus();
    return false;
}
  return true;
}
```

and in server side code
use

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" OnClientClick="return User2Check();" TabIndex="12" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You've misspelled foucs();

The code will stop running after that error.

Answer (score -1):

Since you don't appear to be returning true, put an exclamation mark before the function. For example:

```
!function(){
    // Code here!
}
```

Comment: -1: This will not execute the function itself. This code fragment will always evaluate to false, no matter what the function would actually return.  The negation applies to the function itself, which is normally a truthy value, so it becomes false.